# Building fmt for basic clang cpp windows program - Linker issue?

Tags: c++, cmake, fmt

I'm a beginner to C++ and am trying to compile and use the [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) in a basic program, but I'm having a problem getting it working.  The program, Tester.cpp, is simply as follows:

```
// #define FMT_HEADER_ONLY
// #include <C:\Program Files (x86)\FMT\include\fmt\format.h>
#include <fmt/format.h> 
#include <iostream>
    
int main() {
  std::cout << "C++ Code Executing!" << std::endl;
  int num = 7;
    
 std::cout << fmt::format("The answer is {}.", num) << std::endl;  
}
```

I have never really used cmake before, but have taken the following steps to download and compile the library so far:

```
git clone https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt.git
cd fmt
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
cmake --install .
```

This stores a range of header files into this directory:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\FMT\include\fmt
```

As per the commented lines in my program, if I instruct it to use header only and include a pathway directly to the header file it does seem to work, however I believe I should be able compile the fmt library in a way that I can link to it without using header only, ideally as a static library, (though as a beginner I may be wrong on this).  In it's current format if I compile with clang++ in the following way:

```
clang++ -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\FMT\include" Tester.cpp -o Tester.exe
```

I get the following error:

```
Tester-333c8c.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl fmt::v8::vformat(class fmt::v8::basic_string_view<char>,class fmt::v8::basic_format_args<class fmt::v8::basic_format_context<class fmt::v8::appender,char> >)" (?vformat@v8@fmt@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$basic_string_view@D@12@V?$basic_format_args@V?$basic_format_context@Vappender@v8@fmt@@D@v8@fmt@@@12@@Z) referenced in function main
Tester.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1120 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I believe this is because the compiler can find the header files for compilation, but the linker has no definition/object file to link into an executable?  This is the part I am trying to fix, but have been unable to do so.

As per the instructions for [fmt 8.1.1](https://fmt.dev/latest/usage.html) I have tried using cmake with -DCMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=TRUE to create a static library, resulting in a fmt.lib file, but trying to link to that doesn't seem to help resolve my issues either.  I've also tried adding an -L flag to different directories when compiling, but still get the error.

**Question**

Is someone able to point out where I'm going wrong in trying to compile and use this library for my program?

I am on a Windows system.  I have been using clang and Neovim for code editing, though I do have Visual Studio installed as I believe clang relies on part of the instillation.  I'm ideally looking to do this purely through command line tools if possible.  As a beginner I'm also a bit shaky on how some parts of cpp, such as header files, are supposed to work, should it be relevant.

**EDIT**
As per HolyBlackCat's comment on linking I have also tried the following:

```
clang++ -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\FMT\include" -LC:/FMT -lfmt Tester.cpp -o Tester.exe
```

with fmt.lib located in C:\FMT and get and error that starts like so:

```
fmt.lib(format.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MD_DynamicRelease' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in Tester-6086ae.o
msvcprt.lib(MSVCP140.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __cdecl std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QEAA@H@Z) already defined in libcpmt.lib(xlock.obj)
...
...
Many lines...
...
LINK : warning LNK4217: symbol '_isatty' defined in 'libucrt.lib(isatty.obj)' is imported by 'fmt.lib(format.obj)' in function '"void __cdecl fmt::v8::detail::print(struct _iobuf *,class fmt::v8::basic_string_view<char>)" (?print@detail@v8@fmt@@YAXPEAU_iobuf@@V?$basic_string_view@D@23@@Z)'
Tester.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1169 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: If you compile it to a static library then you likely need to link that static library. I say likely because msvc has a #pragma that can add linker settings.

Comment: *"trying to link to that doesn't seem to help"* How exactly did you link it? It should work.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, consider using `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to get a better installation directory; installing to `Program Files` is fairly unconventional.  *"CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE=TRUE to create a static library"* That's not required to create a static library. You only need it if the static library will be linked into a shared library. *"Visual Studio installed as I believe clang relies on part of the instillation"* It can use either VS or MinGW, depending on which standard library you prefer.

Comment: Please show the full error message

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've tried a command like this : clang++ -isystem "C:\Program Files (x86)\FMT\include" -L "C:\FMT\fmt.lib" Tester.cpp -o Tester.exe

Comment: @AlanBirtles Full error copied in

Comment: That's not how you link a library. `-L` needs a directory (`-LC:/FMT`) You also need `-lfmt` (`.lib` extension will be added automatically).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Edited question to show results of a command based on your suggestion.

Comment: `-l` flags must be after any source or object files, not before. But it seems it's not what causes the issue here.

Comment: `clang`+MSVC is a weird combination, so I'm unsure how to handle this. It would be easier to use `clang`+MinGW (by replacing official Clang binaries with the ones from [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075)). OR use `clang-cl`+MSVC (a wrapper that accepts MSVC-flavored arguments) - then `/MD` flag should fix the issue (I'm not sure if there's an equivalent for the regular `clang`). The former option (clang+mingw), which is what I prefer, gives you the same standard library on all platforms. The latter gives you compatibility with VS (the IDE), if that's what you like.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Do you know what a MSVC/clang & MinGW command would look like? If my overall process is correct I can try to sort one of those environments to test.  I think cmake used MSVC which may be causing an issue.

Comment: For MinGW the command will be the same as what you already use, except I would use a custom `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` (or skip installation completely), since otherwise your installed libraries will be mixed with those installed by MSYS2, I think. As for `clang-cl`, it should accept the same flags as `cl` (MSVC compiler). But I've never used it from the command-line (only from VS, simply by flipping a bool in project settings).

Comment: Additionally, MSYS2 has prebuilt libfmt in its repos. If you decide to install it, `pkg-config --cflags --libs fmt` will tell you the right flags to use it.

Comment: You are approaching to this problem in a wrong way. Acquiring libraries is as easy as `vcpkg install fmt` nowadays. Same for consuming `target_link_libraries(MyApp PRIVATE fmt::fmt)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my eventual solution/workaround,

Following my comment dialog with HolyBlackCat, I decided to remove MSVC and installed a MinGW-w64 environment (via Choclatey winlibs).  I then built FMT via cmake as follows:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
cmake --build .
```

I was then able to compile my program in the following way:

```
clang++ Tester.cpp -o Tester.exe -isystem "C:\Coding\3rd_Party\C++\fmt\include" -L "C:\Coding\3rd_Party\C++\fmt\build" -l:libfmt.a
```

Which resulted in successful compilation and a a runnable executable.

I suspect the issue was that cmake was building using MSVC and then trying to link to that with clang was causing an incompatibility somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should like with the {fmt} library as documented in https://fmt.dev/latest/usage.html. For example, if you are using CMake it can be done as follows:

```
target_link_libraries(<your-target> fmt::fmt)
```